# Where is pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically defined for Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-location, watchos

I am writing an independent WatchOS App that uses CoreLocation.  I want to ensure that location updates are never paused.  Apple defines pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically [here,](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620553-pauseslocationupdatesautomatical) which is exactly what I was looking for.  The only problem is that it is not available for WatchOS apparently.  In an iOS app it is available. Once I realized this, I checked in CLLocationManager.h and it isn't there at all.

Then I found on a Microsoft [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/corelocation.cllocationmanager.pauseslocationupdatesautomatically?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) of all places (Xamarin) that it is unavailable for WatchOS apps, and is available for iOS apps.

How can I find info like this either from Apple's docs or in the header files...this is pretty confusing to me. It was not clear to me on the Apple website that this would be unavailable for a WatchOS app.

Comment: On the Apple page you linked to, look at the list of SDK's on the right - This property is only available on iOS after 6.0 and Mac Catalyst after 13.0

Comment: And so it is...make this an answer and I'll give you credit for it.  Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Apple page you linked to, look at the list of SDK's on the right - This property is only available on iOS after 6.0 and Mac Catalyst after 13.0.

If an SDK isn't listed (watchOS) then it isn't available on that platform.

[image]